# Using flutter how to get scan code from hand held device

Tags: android, flutter, qr-code, barcode, scanning

How to get the scan code from hand held device while clicking the triger button in device and update the text in textfield controller.

I need to capture the scan code from hand held device which can scan the both QR and Bar code and update the textfield controller. Please Help